# Integrating Jython Cpython

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, process, jython

I am about to begin a project where I will likely use PyQt or Pyside.

I will need to interface with a buggy 3rd party piece of server software that provides C++ and Java APIs.  The Java APIs are a lot easier to use because you get Exceptions where with the C++ libraries you get segfaults.  Also, the Python bindings to the Java APIs are automatic with Jython whereas the Python bindings for the C++ APIs don't exist.

So, how would a CPython PyQt client application be able to communicate with these Java APIs?  How would you go about it?

Would you have another separate Java process on the client that serializes / pickles objects and communicates with the PyQt process over a socket?

I don't want to re-invent the wheel... is there some sort of standard interface for these types of things?  Some technology I should look into?  RPC, Corba, etc?

Thanks,
~Eric

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain complete isolation and increase your robustness (the 3rd party library going down and not taking your client, and if it's buggy I would recommend that) then perhaps something like CORBA is the way forwards. Don't forget that Java comes with a CORBA implementation as standard, so you just need to generate your C proxy from the IDL.

[Swig](http://www.swig.org/) may be of interest if you want to run stuff in-process. It simplifies the binding of components in different languages. Note in particular that it [generates bindings for Python and Java](http://www.swig.org/compare.html).

Answer (score 0):

If the criteria is not reinventing the wheel, there is the `SimpleXMLRPCServer` and `xmlrpclib` modules available in the standard library. They should work in Jython too.